# loss.backward() no grad in pytorch NN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

The code gives an error in loss.backward()
Error is:
**untimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn**

```
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    model.train()
    for i,(im1, im2, labels) in enumerate(train_dl):
        i1 = torch.flatten(im1,1)
        i2 = torch.flatten(im2,1)
        inp = torch.cat([i1,i2],1)
        
        b_x = Variable(inp) # batch x
        b_y = Variable(labels) # batch y
        y_ = model(b_x).squeeze()
        y_ = (y_>0.5).float()
        
        print(y_)
        print(l)
        loss = criterion(y_,b_y)
        print(loss.item())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: `y_ > 0.5` <- you can't do this, the binarization creates discontinuity in the graph. What exactly is the purpose of that ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Actually, I am giving 2 flattened images concatenated to the input and output is whether they are of the same person or not.

Comment: That's why I am doing thresholding.

Comment: what is the `.shape` of `y_` ? And what `criterion` it is ?

Comment: y_ is [100,1] tensor and labels are [100] size tensor, due to which I squeezed the y_, I have removed y_ = (y_>0.5) and the error is removed. But my data does not overfit on first batch

Answer (score 1):

```
y_ = (y_>0.5).float()
```

has a zero gradient, intuitively because "tiny changes in the argument lead to absolutely no change in the value (imagine that `y_` changes by tiny epsilon, it does not affect value of `y_`.

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean by "lead to absolutely no change"??

Comment: The model returns the probability, so we did the thresholding to make it zero or one.

Comment: Think about any y_ close to say 0.7. Will y_ be any different if you change it by a tiny epsilon? No, it will be 1 constantly. This is "absolutely no change", an intuitive way to think why gradient will be 0 (and even not implemented). You cannot use thresholding and (at least naive) gradient based learning together. You can use thresholding when computing evaluation metric, but not a loss you want to differentiate. Thats why we minimise cross entropy rather than maximise accuracy etc.

Comment: I meant "will *resulting y_" be any different of course.

Answer (score 1):

With additional info given by OP in the comment, the correct approach here is just removing the line

```
y_ = (y_>0.5).float()
```